# networking icons slightly pushed down in Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

This problem has been driving me crazy, I am doing some cross browser compatibility and I have my site working in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. However there is this very small problem I am noticing and it is driving me nuts. My social networking icons align just as they should in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox but in IE they slip down to what looks like 1 pixel below where should be. I have searched for every kind of issue related to this and I can't seem to find a solution. I have defined, border, padding, margin, outline, line-height, and height and nothing seems to fix it. I have the icons wrapped in a container and displayed as inline-block my. code is below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

HTML

```
    <div class="container" id="facebook"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Revived-Films/132089646842036"><img src="images/127695-simple-black-square-icon-social-media-logos-facebook-logo_fy10-188x188-1.png" alt="Facebook%20Icon"/></a></div>

    <div class="container" id="vimeo"><a href="https://vimeo.com/user4883685/videos"><img src="images/Black-icon_vimeo-188x188-2.png" alt="Vimeo%20Icon"/></a></div>
```

CSS

```
    .container {
      width: 100px;
      height: 22px;
      display: inline;
      margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      line-height: 22px;
      outline: 0px;
      border: 0px;
      }

     #vimeo {
      float: right;
      margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
      height: 22px;
      padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
      width: 24px;
      line-height: 22px;
      outline: 0px;
      border: 0px;
      }

     #facebook {
      float: right;
      margin: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
      height: 22px;
      padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
      width: 24px;
      line-height: 22px;
      outline: 0px;
      border: 0px;
      }

    #facebook a:hover img{
      opacity:0.50;
      }

    #vimeo a:hover img{
      opacity:0.50;
      }
```

Comment: I might recommend looking at this site: (http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-specific-for-internet-explorer)

This would allow you to have CSS targeted to just IE.

Comment: Oh IE? Which version of IE?? **6, 7, 8, 9, 10 or 11?** Did you just copy/paste from a Firebug equivalent? A value of `0px` should be written `0` every time. Both div are floating so `display: inline` won't apply: it's `display: block` in this case per CSS2.1 specification (hint: otherwise `width: 100px` wouldn't have any effect). Finally did you try adding width and height attributes on `img` elements? Playing with `vertical-align` (top maybe)?

Comment: Thank you for the responses, I have tried all of those edits and the icons still hug the bottom dotted line when displayed IE 10. Are there any other properties that might deal with this? I tried all vertical-align properties and none of them seemed to fix the issue. @JimElrod thank you for the link but if it is at all possible I would like to debug the site without using code that targets specific browsers unless I absolutely have to.

Answer (score 0):

try this script, with it you can select each browser or mobile platform specifically in css.

http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/